# Can SSIS packages call other SSIS packages in the connection string?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, password, connection-string

I am running an SSIS package that transfers data from one (SQL2008) server to another (SQL2000). However after P2V conversion the SQL2008 server cannot execute an SSIS package due to a user authentication error.

Lets say the package is called "Transfer-Go". In the connection string of that package can it call another SSIS package? In the SSIS library there is another package with the same that appears in the string (called Transfer-Now) name The string is below:

```
Data Source=<IP>;User ID=<user>;Initial Catalog=<db_name>;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;OLE DB Services=-13;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-<Transfer-Now-name of other SSIS package>-{8ABA18EE-637E-424F-A3F7-F7E4EA50DD9D}<IP.db_name.user>;
```

So is this SSIS package connection string calling that package?

And if the credentials are wrong in that package could that be why I am unable to authenticate?

Thanks for any input, not a DB/SQL guy at all so I apologize if I sound green here.

Answer (score 2):

The connection string is not calling another SSIS Package. The property Application Name is optional filler text so you can differentiate one connection from another.

```
Application Name=SSIS-<Transfer-Now-name of other SSIS package>-{8ABA18EE-637E-424F-A3F7-F7E4EA50DD9D}<IP.db_name.user>
```

If `Transfer-Go` has the a reference to `Transfer-Now` in the connection string, the probable cause is that the developer created `Transfer-Now` and then copy/pasted either the package in whole or at least the Connection Manager between the packages.

The mechanisms for one package to run another package are

- Execute Package Task {either as an in-process (synchronous) or out of process (asynchronous)}
- Execute SQL Task
- Execute Process Task

The later two options will have you either running a predefined Agent Job or building out the appropriate commands to [dtexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)